# Python's nose2 --with-coverage is showing coverage for the test itself

Tags: python, nose2

I'm trying to follow Chapter 3 of David Sale's [Testing Python](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118901223.html), but using `nose2` instead of `nosetests`. So far I've written a `calculate.py`:

```
class Calculate(object):
    def add(self, x, y):
        if type(x) == int and type(y) == int:
            return x + y
        else:
            raise TypeError("Invalid type: {} and {}".format(type(x), type(y)))

if __name__ == '__main__':      # pragma: no cover
    calc = Calculate()
    result = calc.add(2, 2)
    print(result)
```

and, in a subdirectory `test`, a `test_calculator.py`:

```
import unittest
from calculate import Calculate

class TestCalculate(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.calc = Calculate()

    def test_add_method_returns_correct_result(self):
        self.assertEqual(4, self.calc.add(2,2))

    def test_add_method_raises_typeerror_if_not_ints(self):
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, self.calc.add, "Hello", "World")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

If I run `nose2 --with-coverage` in the main directory, I get

```
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.002s

OK
----------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.5.2-final-0 -----------
Name                     Stmts   Miss  Cover
--------------------------------------------
calculate.py                 5      0   100%
test/test_calculate.py      11      1    91%
--------------------------------------------
TOTAL                       16      1    94%
```

I don't understand why a coverage is calculated for the testing program `test/test_calculate.py` as well as for the main program, `calculate.py`. Is there any way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--coverage` parameter to measure coverage only for the given path. In your example, you need to run

```
nose2 --with-coverage --coverage calculate
```

This will give you the expected output:

```
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.002s

OK
----------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.5.2-final-0 -----------
Name           Stmts   Miss  Cover
----------------------------------
calculate.py       5      0   100%
```